# Orderby wordpress with big numbers

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The marketcap is saved like this into my database: 968,953, 92,673,921 etc. So the wordpress thinks that what is before first quote it's decimal. Making 968,953 to be in front of 92,673,921. Anyone has any idea how to do this, without changing the numbers in SQL?

```
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => array('coins'),

        'posts_per_page' => 20,

        'paged' => $paged,

        'meta_key' => 'market_cap',
        
        'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num',

        'order' => 'DESC',
);
```

Comment: Try make the orderby an array like so `'orderby' => ['meta_value', 'meta_value_num']`.

Comment: Not working, it gives the same result.

Comment: Why not store the value correctly?

Comment: @Strawberry changed everything and now i'm storing them corectly.

Comment: Great. So I guess we can Close this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value explicitly as an integer

```
'orderby' => 'CAST(REPLACE(meta_value,",","") as unsigned)'
```

or

```
'orderby' => 'CAST(REPLACE(meta_value_num,",","") as unsigned)'
```

Not sure which of those contains the value you're trying to sort by

Comment: Neither are working. Second looks like this: 53,392, 102,627, 1,467,106, 792,363, 137,718, 34,666,930

First 346,575, 312,358, 306, 291,872, 232,912,502

Comment: well there are 2 sorts in there, what if you remove one? just keep meta_value or meta_value_num?

Comment: Tried with both, same result.53,392, 102,627, 1,467,106

Comment: pls see revised answer. the comma was the issue

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string ") as unsigned), meta_value_num", expecting ")"

Modified like this;

orderby' => 'CAST(REPLACE(meta_value_num,",","") as unsigned)',

still not working

Comment: sorry about the breaking single quotes - are the values stored in meta_value or meta_value_num?

Comment: .. and just to be thorough, `"CAST(REPLACE(meta_value,',','') as unsigned)"` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @CAST(REPLACE(meta_value,',','') as unsigned) not working, gives me Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string ") as unsigned)", expectin

using php 8.06

Comment: Sorry, it must be the quote differences. try `'CAST(REPLACE(meta_value,",","") as unsigned)'`

Comment: I updated the answer for the single quote enclosure

Comment: Not working, it might be from php 8.0 something, because the numbers are not integers, let me change it to 7 and see if it works. NVM, not working.